# The lebesgue integral of a strictly greater than zero function is strictly greater than zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space, a function $f : X → [0,\infty]$ be $\Sigma$-
measurable, and $A\in\Sigma$ with $\mu(A) > 0$.
I want to show if
$$f(x) > 0, x\in A,$$
then
$$\int_A fd\mu>0,$$
without using the following Property of the Lebesgue
Integral:
if $f:A\rightarrow [0,\infty]$, then
$$\int_A fd\mu=0\iff f(x)= 0\,\,\,\text{a.e}\,\, \mu\,\,\text{on}\,\, A.$$
I have proven this before using the above property but proving it without it is providing me with trouble. Any recommendations on where to start?

Comment: *Hint:* Since $$A \subseteq \{f > 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f > 1/n\}, $$ you can find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\mu(\{f > \varepsilon\})>0$. Now use the fact that $f \geq \varepsilon \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{f>\varepsilon\}} $.

Comment: Prove this for simple functions from the definition of the Lebesgue integrals for simple functions. Then use a density argument in conjunction with monotonic convergence theorem

Comment: on second thoughts my suggestion may be difficult since you cannot arrange for the simple functions in the approximation of $f$ to be strictly greater than zero.